# Python - Adding idle time after every X inserts into a table (using API)

Tags: python, api

I have the below code that I use to insert into a table

```
data = {"name": name, "product": product}
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
data = {
        "name": data["name"],
        "type": data["product"]}
response = requests.post(url=API_ENDPOINT, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
resp_dump = json.dumps(response.json())
resp_load = json.loads(resp_dump)
```

The above code works well. I however am trying to see how can I add a idle time after every 10 inserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can always use time

```py
from time import sleep
i = 0
while True:
    # insert in table
    if i % 10 == 0:
        sleep(10)
    i += 1
```

Comment: dude you didn't change `i` anywhere